# Publish Kinect Depth information to a Ros Topic

Tags: ros, python, kinect, openni-camera, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, all,

Recently, we've been attempting to access the kinect depth data from the published point cloud provided by the openni_node, but we've run into a couple stumbling points:

first, the ros tutorial for pcl_ros

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Tutorials/CloudToImage

references a topic published by openni called:
/camera/depth/points2
but our version of openni_kinect only publishes:
/camera/depth/points
Are we using an outdated version?

Also, we tried working with /camera/depth/points and we believe that this information is published in binary format.  When we attempted to convert the binary format of a single point to x,y,z information though, we received a list of 4 integers.  Are we interpreting the information incorrectly?

We also subscribed to the /camera/depth/image, and we could access the depth information from a single point, but we're restricted to meter-by-meter resolution.  Is there a better way of getting more resolution with the /camera/depth/image ?

Thanks for reading, and we appreciate any directions you can point us to accessing the depth information (of points) from the kinect.

Sincerely,

Poofjunior

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10591/publish-kinect-depth-information-to-a-ros-topic/) by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2011-07-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current driver publishes both point clouds and images:

- /camera/depth/points -- this is the non-colored point cloud. To use this, you'd probably want to use PCL (Point Cloud Library) functions to access individual points in a meaningful manner.
- /camera/depth/image -- this is the depth image (not a point cloud). It can easily be converted to an OpenCV image using the cv_bridge package. For using the depth image, it is important to note that is a 32-bit float for each pixel, corresponding to meters. [This](http://answers.ros.org/question/1189/openni_camera-depth-image-opencv#1994) answer and [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/869/kinect-opencv#1485) contain some useful information on using the image.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-07-14**:
Great! Please click the checkmark next to my answer to accept it.

**Comment by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on 2011-07-14**:
Many thanks, fergs!  It turns out that we weren't interpreting the image correctly.  We changed                                  cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv(data, "mono8")      to      cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv(data, "32FC1")    and we started seeing much better results.

**Comment by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on 2011-07-14**:
Many thanks, fergs!

**Comment by [Consider1001](https://answers.ros.org/users/12511/consider1001/) on 2014-04-15**:
Thank you for your answer. May I ask a question that if there is a way to get the value(float) of each point on the depth/image_raw before we convert it in to a cvmat?